# Why Macbuntu pack always corrupts my system?

Tags: package-management, repository

Are noobslab repositories safe to add to my repository lists?

I am asking this because Macbuntu transformation pack corrupted my system many times. My system would have missing icons. Sometimes it didn't even boot and I had to perform a re installation.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo